# I cannot add and delete my cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried to add my function in the Seoul Region.

```
exports.iowa = functions.region("us-central1").https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors()(req, res, () => {
    res.send("Hi from Iowa, USA")
  })
})

exports.london = functions
  .region("europe-west2")
  .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors()(req, res, () => {
      res.send("Hi from London, UK")
    })
  })

exports.hongkong = functions
  .region("asia-east2")
  .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors()(req, res, () => {
      res.send("Hi from Hongkong, Hongkong")
    })
  })

exports.seoul = functions
  .region("asia-northeast3")
  .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors()(req, res, () => {
      res.send("Hi from Seoul, Korea")
    })
  })
```

But I faced this error.

> functions: failed to create function seoul
> HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied on 'locations/asia-northeast3' (or it may not exist).

I cannot see that function in my cloud functions console and firebase console too.
But the weirdest thing is this function is really working now.

[image]

And I cannot delete that function with cli command

> firebase-test> firebase functions:delete seoul
> Error: The specified filters do not match any existing functions in project

How can I add or delete that function with that Tier 2 region (asia-northeast3)

Comment: If the Firebase CLI is not giving you helpful error messages, you might want to contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: In the GCP project associated with your Firebase project, can you see the functions? https://console.cloud.google.com/functions  ,did you tried list the functions via [Gcloud SDK commands](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/list)?